# Prettier VS Code - how a JS object is formatted

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I got this object:

```
const map = {
        '&amp;': '&', '&#038;': '&', '&lt;': '<', '&gt;': '>', '&quot;': '"', '&#039;': "'", '&#8217;': '’',
        '&#8216;': '‘', '&#8211;': '–', '&#8212;': '—', '&#8230;': '…', '&#8221;': '”'
    };
```

And prettier automatically formats it to:

```
const map = {
    '&amp;': '&',
    '&#038;': '&',
    '&lt;': '<',
    '&gt;': '>',
    '&quot;': '"',
    '&#039;': "'",
    '&#8217;': '’',
    '&#8216;': '‘',
    '&#8211;': '–',
    '&#8212;': '—',
    '&#8230;': '…',
    '&#8221;': '”'
};
```

How can I configure it to stay as the original?

Comment: https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html

Answer (score -1):

The first code is a minified code. You should try to install the minify plugin for VSCode ad add a keyboard shortcut to minify your code as the first one.

Comment: "The first code is a minified code. " — No it isn't. If it was then all of the optional whitespace would have been stripped.